# Do Gatling reports req/s include pauses and pace?

Tags: performance, load, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm running load tests in gatling, and noticed when I ramp 250 users over 10 seconds, the report gives me an average of 31 req/s:

```
val combinedScenario = scenario("Combined")
.feed(UuidFeeder.feeder)
.exec(_.set("token", token))
.exec(saveData)
.exec(processDocumentRequest)
)

val scn = List(OAuthRequest.inject(atOnceUsers(1)),
    combinedScenario.inject(nothingFor(5 seconds),
    rampUsers(250) over (10 seconds)));

setUp(scn).protocols(httpConf).maxDuration(60 minutes)
```

However, when I surround the scenario in a forever loop and put a 60 second pace in between each set of requests, the report then says I average about 8 req/s:

```
val combinedScenario = scenario("Combined")
.feed(UuidFeeder.feeder)
.exec(_.set("token", token))
.forever(
  pace(60 seconds)
    .exec(saveData)
    .exec(processDocumentRequest)
)
```

Is this simply because the report factors in the 50 seconds in between iterations where 0 requests are being sent? Can I assume that it's still sending around 31 req/s for the short bursts of requests being sent each minute?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the reports just show what the actual throughout during the scenario was, not some hypothetical maximum. The number you get could be constrained by your scenario or by the application under test. You would need to run some experiments to confirm.

With the pace in the scenario, you should also be able to increase the number of concurrent users, based on your initial testing